# DllNotFoundException: Не удается загрузить DLL

Tags: c#

Установил через диспетчер пакетов nuget библиотеку pjsua. используя `using` подключаю ее и все нормально, могу использовать классы и методы. В `reference` она тоже добавлена. Однако при компиляции получаю ошибку `DllNotFoundException`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using pjsip4net.Accounts;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using org.pjsip.pjsua2;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        class MyAccount : Account
        {

            public override void onRegState(OnRegStateParam prm)
            {
                base.onRegState(prm);
                System.Console.WriteLine("*** On registration state: " + prm.code.ToString() + prm.reason.ToString());
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Endpoint endpoint = new Endpoint();
            endpoint.libCreate();
            EpConfig config = new EpConfig();
            endpoint.libInit(config);
            TransportConfig transportConfig = new TransportConfig();
            transportConfig.port = 5060;

            AccountSipConfig accountSipConfig = new AccountSipConfig();
            AccountCallConfig accountCallConfig = new AccountCallConfig();


            AccountConfig accountConfig = new AccountConfig();
            accountConfig.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:pjsip.org";
            accountConfig.idUri = "sip:test@pjsip.org";
            accountConfig.callConfig = accountCallConfig;
            AuthCredInfo authCredInfo = new AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "test", 0, "secret");
            accountSipConfig.authCreds.Add(authCredInfo);
            accountConfig.sipConfig = accountSipConfig;


            MyAccount myAccount = new MyAccount();
            myAccount.create(accountConfig);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В выходной папке библиотека есть указанная?

Comment: @Андрей Да, лежит в папке Bin\debug

Comment: Возможно, у вашей библиотеки есть зависимость от других библиотек (посмотрите через Depends.exe). Вот эти зависимости, наверное, и не находятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок поиска для dll библиотки:

1. Текущий каталог, где лежит запускаемое приложение
2. Системная папка `C:\Windows\system32` или `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
   (папка системных библиотек для запуска 32-разрядных приложений на 64-разрядной Windows), но можно положить в оба места (если не поможет - можно в конечном счете удалить библиотеку из системной папки).
3. Чтение из переменной окружения `Path`

Соответственно, советов несколько:

1. Проверить наличие библиотеки в текущем рабочем каталоге, при отсутствии вставить библиотеку в этот каталог. Если библиотека есть, но ошибка падает - перейти к шагу два
2. Скопировать библиотеку в системную папку (в зависимости от разрядности процессора), если не помогло - перейти к шагу три
3. Проверить в деталях исключения, откуда пытается загрузить библиотеку приложение и положить ее туда

Можно проверить зависимости DLL, поисковик зависимостей предоставляемый Visual Studio, может помочь, его можно бесплатно скачать:  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Ссылка на источник: [Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003290/5275890)

Comment: Так судя по всему он библиотеку определяется. Но почему-то не инициализирует. То есть если я создам объект класса и не инициализирую его, то он не выдаст эту ошибку.

Comment: @Идентикон попробуй для типа объекта писать полный путь, включая пространство имен. Может конфликтует

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, все та же ошибка

Comment: @Идентикон посмортите сведения об исключении. Приведите полный текст и StackTrace исключения. Посмотрите путь, откуда пытается загрузить библиотеку.